# aspnet core encrypting and decrypting a string

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core

I am trying to decrypt a string using some pretty standard algorithm.

```
public static string DecryptString(string cipherText)
{
    string keyString = string.Empty;

    // Check whether the environment variable exists.
    keyString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EncryptKey");

    if (keyString == null)
    {
        keyString = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";
    }

    var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        byte[] iv = new byte[aesAlg.BlockSize / 8];
        var cipher = new byte[16];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

        string result;
        using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
        {
            result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error :

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.

I have tried multiple ways like this

```
var iv = new byte[16];
var cipher = new byte[16];
```

Or

```
var iv = aesAlg.IV;
```

I still get an error at this point. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919228/specified-key-is-not-a-valid-size-for-this-algorithm)

Comment: How was the message encrypted, what language and implementation such as PHP mcrypt

Comment: [@w2olves] have you solved that?

Comment: @Eris This is not a duplicate 1) This is AES, that's not. 2) If we define key length 15, then we got the key size exception, but with 16 we got other exception (this padding thing, what the question is about)

Comment: @w2olves have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @IvanZaruba  I am still facing this issue.

Comment: @w2olves can you show the EncryptString method? A possible reason for the exception to be fired could be if you concatenate IV + cipher in a wrong order

Comment: By changing the value for `cipher` and altering the second `Buffer.BlockCopy` statement as mentioned in this link solves this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541503/4745542

Answer (score 1):

Two changes are required

```
var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - iv.Length];
```

and

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, fullCipher.Length - iv.Length);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
  {
     string EncryptionKey  = string.Empty;

    // Check whether the environment variable exists.
    EncryptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EncryptKey");

    if (EncryptionKey == null)
    {
        EncryptionKey = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";
    }
            byte[] cipherBytes;
            try
            {
                cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            }
            catch
            {
                return cipherText;
            }
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
```

**Note :-** You need to provide same key which you provided for encryption the string.

Comment: This is a block of code that's copy-pasted all over the web and this site. Mention where you found it, and why it's a good choice to do what the OP wants.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am using this code. i did not copy from anywhere. I add this code from multiple places.