# Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm - c# - System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, system

pretty new to c# and currently having a problem decrypting long passwords with an error of

> Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

I know this has something to do with the encrypted password bits length not being supported but unsure how to go about suggested ways to allow for these longer passwords.

Here's my encrypt and decrypt

> "cipherKey": "0123456789abcdef",    "cipherVector":
>   "somereallycooliv"

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace DataApi
{
public class Encryption
{
    private readonly IConfigurationService _configService;


    private const string _vector = "cipherVector";
    private const string _key = "cipherKey";

    public Encryption(IConfigurationService configService)
    {
        _configService = configService;
    }
    public string EncryptString(string text)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return "";
        }
        try
        {

      var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configService.Get(_key));
        byte[] IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configService.Get(_vector));

        using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, IV))
            {
                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(text);
                    }

                    var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                    var result = new byte[IV.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(IV, 0, result, 0, IV.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, IV.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
             Loggifer.Error("Unable to encrypt string: "+text , e );

            throw e;
        }
    }

    public string DecryptString(string cipherText)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
        {
            return "";
        }
        try
        {
            var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            byte[] IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configService.Get(_vector));
            var cipher = new byte[16];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, IV, 0, IV.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, IV.Length, cipher, 0, IV.Length);
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configService.Get(_key));

            using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
                {
                    string result;
                    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
                    {
                        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Loggifer.Error("Unable to decrypt string: "+cipherText , e );
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: `cipher` should be `new byte[fullCipher.Length - IV.Length]`. You're probably missing trailing blocks in your data.

Comment: If these are user passwords that you're encrypting, just throw away this code because you shouldn't be doing this. User passwords must be *hashed*, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two changes are required in the function `public string DecryptString(string cipherText)`

```
 var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - IV.Length];
```

and

```
 Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, IV.Length, cipher, 0, fullCipher.Length - IV.Length);
```