# Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm when using AES & PKCS#7 padding in .Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, .net-core, aes

I spent a whole day investigating this and search all related questions on Stack Overflow for this question so please don't mention about possible duplicates.

The code below gives me a **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.'**

While using the very same parameters on this website : http://aes.online-domain-tools.com it decrypts perfectly into "Hello world" then filled with five 'x05' bytes for padding (PKCS#7 padding).

However the code below will always yield an exception when calling the `TransformFinalBlock()`

Context:
Console application running on Win8.1 with .NET Core 2.0 / Algorithm is AES / CBC / padding PKCS#7

I also tried the proposed solution here: [Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm - c# - System.Security.Cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533454/specified-padding-mode-is-not-valid-for-this-algorithm-c-sharp-system-securi) but no success (I also don't understand why if IV is already set in the SymmetricAlgorithm instance, it should be used later on when deciphering?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string encryptedStr = "e469acd421dd71ade4937736c06fdc9d";
        string passphraseStr = "1e089e3c5323ad80a90767bdd5907297b4138163f027097fd3bdbeab528d2d68";
        string ivStr = "07dfd3f0b90e25e83fd05ba338d0be68";

        // Convert hex strings to their ASCII representation
        ivStr = HexStringToString(ivStr);
        passphraseStr = HexStringToString(passphraseStr);
        encryptedStr = HexStringToString(encryptedStr);

        // Convert our ASCII strings to byte arrays
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedStr);
        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passphraseStr);
        byte[] iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivStr);

        // Configure our AES decryptor
        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = Aes.Create();
        algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        algorithm.KeySize = 256;
        //algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
        algorithm.Key = key;
        algorithm.IV = iv;

        Console.WriteLine("IV length " + iv.Length);            // 16
        Console.WriteLine("Key length " + key.Length);          // 32

        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);

        // Perform decryption
        byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);

        // Convert it back to a string
        string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputBuffer);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string HexStringToString(string hexString)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            var hexChar = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
            sb.Append((char)Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way how you convert hex string to byte array. Try to debug your code and check the value of array `encryptedBytes`. You'll see the following array:

```
{ 0x3f, 0x69, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x21, 0x3f, 0x71, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x77, 0x36, 0x3f, 0x6f, 0x3f, 0x3f }
```

which is far from input `e469acd421dd71ade4937736c06fdc9d`.

You shouldn't use `System.String` object as just a holder of binary char codes because .Net strings are UTF16-encoded.

Now when root cause is clear, the fix is pretty straighforward. Change your `HexStringToString` method so that it converts hex string to bytes array directly:

```
public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Inalid hex string '{hexString}'");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
    {
        var hexChar = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Then adjust the code in `Main()`:

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = HexStringToByteArray(encryptedStr);
byte[] key = HexStringToByteArray(passphraseStr);
byte[] iv = HexStringToByteArray(ivStr);
```

This will give you desired `Hello world` in `result` variable.